# How to close edges with straight lines to form closed contours in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edges

I am using the Canny Edge Detector to detect the edges of an object against the background so I can segregate it after either using contour filtering or the grabcut algorithm.

```
        edges = cv2.Canny(blurred_image, 0.1*np.iinfo(image.dtype).max, 0.6*np.iinfo(image.dtype).max, L2gradient = True).astype(np.uint8)

        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5, 5))

        kernel = None

        edges = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel)

        contour_info = [(c, cv2.contourArea(c)) for c in cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]]

        for contour, _ in contour_info:

            for i, _ in enumerate(contour):

                contour[i] = cv2.convexHull(contour[i])
        
        self.save_contour(contour_info, image)
        
        image_area = image.shape[0] * image.shape[1]

        min_area = self.min_area * image_area
        
        max_area = self.max_area * image_area

        mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype = np.uint8)
```

However, the edges remain open which causes the mask to also not separate the shapes. An example is: [The circular edge shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEBxw.png). I was wondering if it's possible to close those edges using straight lines. Dilate and erode do not really achieve my goal so I was wondering if there is an approach involving Hough Lines.

Comment: This is not what Canny edge detection is for. I suggest you take two steps back and rethink your segmentation strategy.

Comment: @CrisLuengo My understanding was that I can generate a mask from the edges. Is that approach wrong?

Comment: You could generate a mask from the edges, but if the edges are not complete, then it's hard. Depending on what your image looks like, there likely are much simpler methods to generate a mask.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you are trying to do, but if you would like to close the shape, you may try [Convex Hull](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d1d/tutorial_hull.html) to create something like a closed contour around your shapes. This will draw straight lines for non-connected areas. :)